# Need best solution to insert data to remote database

Tags: php, mysql, curl, mysqli

I am developing php application using my sql database , both application and database is hosted on **same server(on client server)**.

we want to keep track of some tables of that database and for this purpose we had created same tables in our side at **different server(vendor server).**

what will be the best way to insert that rows at remote side tables as soon as rows are inserted to client database tables?

**Note:** Rows to be inserted may be 50000 or 50 at a time.

Options in front of me:

**1)** To use two connections and will insert rows in both database , But it will take time as i have to insert rows in  large numbers.

**2)** Using curl request to remote database and insert data after rows was inserted in local database

Answer (score 4):

Use mysql built in master/slave setup to keep the databases in sync with each other

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i have just discussed this option with my DBA , But he said using Master-slave replication will give client users access to our server , so we cant do this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a master / slave replication  and let the database itself worry about staying in sync. That will be much more robust than a hand rolled system.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i have just discussed this option with my DBA , But he said using Master-slave replication will give client users access to our server , so we cant do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using replication sounds ideal solution, as other forks commented. But if it's not allowed unfortunately, then it depends requirement.

If the client application can wait so long until 50000 or 50 lines of data is inserted successfully(I guess it takes more than a few seconds if the rows are 50000), then both options in front of you would be still valid.

However, if you need to send the http response back to the client application as fast as possible, then there might be better solution. For example

- prepare some async worker process using crond or any process/daemon you'd like
- every single http request which is created by the client application will store/enqueue record via memcache, syslog or message queue or even using file(only if Disk I/O is not a problem)
- let async worker fetch/dequeue the data, and let him insert 50000 or 50 data sending

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your server as a Slave server to the clients server (which would be the Master), replicating the data on the clients server.

You can also choose to only replicate specific tables or a specific database.

It's quite simple to set up and sounds like it would do what you require.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i have just discussed this option with my DBA , But he said using Master-slave replication will give client users access to our server , so we cant do this.